# TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating'_this.scrollView.scrollTo') in react native

Tags: react-native

In IOS devices when we rotate the screen from portrait to landscape or vice-versa the app gets crashed giving the error as shown in the image. [Error while rotating the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtRtW.png). This is the code I use  for the scroll view

```
componentDidMount{

  let scrollValue = 0;
  const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
  setTimeout(() => {
   scrollValue = scrollValue + dim.width;
   this._scrollView.scrollTo({x: scrollValue})}, 15000);
}

 <ScrollView 
 ref={scrollView => this._scrollView = scrollView}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this._scrollView.scrollTo` is null.

To use a ref you should use `this._scrollView.current.scrollTo({x: scrollValue})}, 15000)`, as reported in the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs